# Anime about a club of high school girls that fight monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember this watching this anime, with like *Madoka Magica* vibes, about a high school club of girl members that (they dont know why it just happens) have to fight against monsters. I dont remember the name but I remember these details:

- The girls would obtain this "uniform" and weapons during the fights that would happen when (if I remember well) time froze and monsters would appear.
- There was one girl in a wheelchair that, during the fights, could move thanks to this gear that appeared when fighting, like long tape like tentacles.
- When the characters used too much force or had to make great amounts of effort with a body part, they would lose it in the real/ normal world when they came back.
- One of the girls realizes that she lost her sense of taste when she came back from a battle, and they offered them a banquet and she drank some juice but couldnt taste it.
- And finally, a girl lost all her mobility, and I think conciousness, after fighting too much and too long with the monsters.

Pls pls pleaseee help me find it, I have been looking for it like crazy.

Comment: (I haven't watched the anime so I could be wrong) but girl in wheelchair = YuYuYu?

Comment: @ahiijny looks like a very solid match, please post it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Yuuki Yuuna wa Yuusha de Aru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki_Yuna_Is_a_Hero)* (AKA *Yuki Yuna Is a Hero*)

[image]

Plot summary from Wikipedia:

> The story takes place on the Japanese island Shikoku in the fictional city of Sanshu, based on the real-life city of Kan'onji in Kagawa Prefecture, in the 300th year of the Era of the Gods. Yūna, Mimori, Fū, and Itsuki are all members of the Sanshu Middle School Hero Club, dedicating themselves to helping those in need. One day in their regular daily lives, the Hero Club members are suddenly caught in an explosion of light and transported to a strange forest, where they encounter mysterious monsters known as Vertex which seek to destroy the Shinju ("Divine Tree"), the guardian deity which protects and blesses humanity. Using a special phone application granted by Taisha, an organization dedicated to the Shinju, Yuna and her friends must transform into "heroes" with magical powers to protect their world from imminent destruction.

The girls -- all members of the [Sanshuu Middle School Hero Club](https://yuyuyu.fandom.com/wiki/Hero_Club) (Hero Club for short) -- transform into costumes when going into battle, as you described:

The wheelchair-bound girl you mentioned, [Mimori Togo](https://yuyuyu.fandom.com/wiki/Tougou_Mimori), holds herself upright with ribbons extending from her battle costume.

[image]

The titular character, [Yuna Yuki](https://yuyuyu.fandom.com/wiki/Yuuki_Yuuna), temporarily lost her sense of taste, her mobility and consciousness:

> As a result of using her Mankai form, she loses her sense of taste. Later, she uses the Mankai form for a second time and loses the use of her legs. Having fallen into a coma due to her efforts, she regains consciousness after Mimori's voice reaches her, as actually her soul was out of her body in a black hole-like realm. She soon recovers and regains her sense of taste and the ability to walk.

Comment: Omg thanks! Thats exactly the anime i was looking for. I had gone crazy looking for it